# Download modified excel file in react

Tags: java, reactjs, file

I am working on REACT JavaScript and Java application.

On a react page, onclick of a button (react), it should manipulate data, append in Excel (Java), and then download it on the local machine.

In React I tried:

```
              <Link
                to="/files/DataList.xlsx"
                target="_blank"
                download
                className="limited-anchor text-muted small"
              >
                
                Download Template
              </Link>
```

But here I need to give a path to download the data. (I can't not hardcode the path with my requirement)

From Java side:

```
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(productData);
    File file=new File("C:\\Users\\ME\\Downloads\\OutputData.csv");
    String csv = CDL.toString(jsArray);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
```

This just stores the data in the location.

Expected flow: Onclick of Download button on react page, it should create file and download automatically in Downloads (Windows/MAC).

Is there any way to handle this entire flow?

Comment: just write the API endpoint and put your logic there and give download button on the React JS UI.

Comment: @Rajesh with java API will i be able to achieve proper file download system rather than just copy pasting. With react u see the downloaded file in the chrome and u get few options (to view folder etc)

Comment: As dev you don't have access for download file location in browser it's depends on user machine/browser settings.You have control on click of button you can start the download that's it. you don't have access more than part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with following approach:

```
download(){
     
    var re = this.state.ReportData;    // Arraylist fetched from java API with headers and row data
    var csvStrings = re.join("%0A");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "data:attachment/csv," + csvStrings;
    a.target = "_Blank";
    a.download = "Report.csv";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
```